# Measure of distance between two curves described by their curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

I have two curves both of which start at $(0,0)$. They satisfy the following equations:

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{d\theta} &= -\frac{\sin \theta}{\kappa(\theta)} \\ 
\frac{dy}{d\theta} &= \text{ }\frac{\cos \theta}{\kappa(\theta)}\\
\kappa(\theta) &= \cos^2 \theta \left[(2-x) \cos \theta - (1+y)\sin \theta\right]
\end{align*}
$

Angle $\theta$ is the angle of the outward normal to the curve. The curve is parametrized by $\theta$ which ranges from $-\pi/2< \theta_0< -\pi/4$ to $0$.

While the two curves, $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$, satisfy the same DEs and start at the origin, their initial data differs in their angle $\theta_0$. Say, $\theta_0^{\mathcal{C}_1} < \theta_0^{\mathcal{C}_2}$.

The picture below is perhaps more helpful to understand what $\theta$ is and also how the curves look.

[image]

I am interested in understanding how far the curves are when $\theta = 0$. Obviously, this is very easy to do numerically. But, are there any analytical methods that I can exploit to understand the difference between their $x$-coordinate as well as their $y$-coordinate?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to understand the notation. $k(\theta)$ should  actually be $k(\theta,x,y)$, i.e., it depends not only on $\theta$ itself, but on the point corresponding to $\theta$ as well, right?

Comment: Not really right? $x,y$ are both functions of $\theta$. The curves are parametrized by $\theta$.

Comment: $x,y$ are not functions of $\theta$ but functions of $\theta$ and $\theta_0$. However, I guess, I can read your answer as "yes".

OK, I'll think of it a bit then. How much do you want to know (the explicit formula is almost certainly out of question)?

Comment: You are right, they are also functions of $\theta_0$. Should have been more specific. Thanks.

Yeah, I don't think I should be hoping for an explicit formula. Can we have some sort of bound i.e. If I change from $\theta_0$ to $\theta_0 + \epsilon$ then how do $x$ and $y$ move? e.g., is the $x$ distance more than $y$?

Comment: **is the x distance more than y?** It is always the other way around, i.e., the change in $y$ is greater than in $x$. Switch to $z=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta$ and $w=-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$. We have $(z,w)=(x,y)$ at the ends but now the equations are like $\dot z=w,\dot w=-z+\frac 1{\text{something}-z}$. Going over $[\theta_0-\varepsilon,\theta _0]$ brings us to the position like $(\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon)$, after which it is clear that you always have an excess in the pull up compared to the initial position $(0,0)$ and that excess is never rotated by more than $45^\circ$ to the right.

Comment: Are you sure about what you wrote, by the way? It is clear that your picture disagrees with your text ($\theta$ on the picture starts at $-\pi/2$, for instance, which is way left of the declared interval $[-\pi/4,0]$ for $\theta_0$).

Comment: Damn, you are absolutely right! Meant $\theta_0 < -\pi/4$. Changed it. $-\pi/2 < \theta_0 < -\pi/4$ Thanks a lot!

This also means, however, that we need to add a scalar or something to $z$ and $w$ for the the initial point to match $(x,y)$.

Comment: **This also means, however, that we need to add a scalar or something to z and w for the the initial point to match (x,y).** Why? $(0,0)$ is still mapped to $(0,0)$. Or are the initial data different from what is written too?

Comment: You are right! The initial data is correct I just didn't understand the change of variables to be honest.